# How do I show decoupled NMR spectra in chemmacros?

Tags: chemmacros

the `chemmacros` has some lovely codes for listing NMR data: `\NMR{31,P}` for example, and the whole `experimental` environment. However, I do a lot of decoupled NMR work, which would be listed as [image: 31P{1H}] (31P spectrum, with 1H decoupled) for example. Is there a way to typeset this using the `chemmacros` package, or do I have to do it by hand?

MWE-like-thing:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
What I can do:

\begin{experimental}
    \NMR{31,P}
        \val{12.24}(d);
\end{experimental}

What I would like:

\(^{31}\text{P}\{^{1}\text{H}\}\)-NMR: \(\delta\) 12.24(d);

\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: The output of the MWE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation, p.31 (angle brackets removed):

> \NMR{num,elem[coupling core]}(num,unit)[solvent]
>
> This command gets an additional argument: \NMR{13,C[^1H]}

Hence in your case you can write

```
\NMR{31,P[^1H]} \val{12.24}(d);
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't heard of the decoupled nucleus referred to that way before, thank you!